# PCB header pins sealing

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, connector, pins, environmental-sealing

I am looking to seal the bottom part of this PCB header because I do not want the pins underneath the connector to be exposed to the environment in which the board will be assembled:

https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-776262-1.html

[image: AMPseal PCB header]

The pins are too long for the glue/silicone type of conformal coating, also the PCB assembly factory cannot shoot the silicone underneath the connector at an angle.

I am looking at having a custom rubber seal made specifically for this but am wondering, are there some other options available?

Comment: Did you look into Parylene?

Comment: When you say pin length is an issue for conformal coating, I assume you actually mean the actual application of spraying or brushing it in from the side, not the nature of the conformal coating itself. Manual application out of the question? Although, if you are concerned about moisture why aren't you coating the entire board (or are you already?) Paraylene that SteveSH mentioned will do that since it is vacuum vapour deposited which of course means your new worry is how not to coat the parts you want exposed.

Comment: @DKNguyen - Obviously, you have to mask off the places you don't want coated.  Like mating surfaces of connectors and heat sinks, or an optical path.  Usually that's it, at least for the boards I've dealt with.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's not a concern about moisture but about general technical cleanliness (previous issues with small metal particles). We want to cover as much as possible to relax the cleanliness constraint on the assembly line of the final product. Manual application is out of the question as this board will end up being mass produced.

Comment: @InsaneMonkey - You're not going to solve a FOD (foreign object debris) issue by coatings.  Coating may help, but they are not a panacea for a dirty production line.  Clean up the production line!

Comment: @InsaneMonkey  Are you conformal coating the PCBA itself?  If so, what process and material are you using for the PCBA?

Comment: Will this board be mounted inside an enclosure? if so, why not rely on the rubber seal of the connector?

Comment: @Insane Monkey - The production will be cleaned but the question is to what extent. It is very costly to clean up a massive production line. We are looking at ways to de-risk the boards in order to relax the cleanliness requirement.

Parylene coating was a good idea but takes too much time to be effective with the quantities we are looking at.

Comment: @AnasMalas - We are looking to protect against particles that could enter the enclosure on the production line before it is closed.

Comment: @InsaneMonkey - "It is very costly to clean up a massive production line."  Maybe, if it's dirty in the first place.  But not to keep one clean on going.  What I'm talking about is just good practice to keep a line clean (clean being a relative term).  I'm not talking about class 100K cleanliness.  And don't take this the wrong way, but I'm not sure who would want your product if it comes off a dirty production line, again dirty being a relative term.

Comment: And your last comment is not consistent with your question, where your asked about pins underneath the connector being exposed to the environment in which the board will be working.

Comment: @InsaneMonkey Just to be clear, we are not a PCB manufacturing company nor an electronics company. We make products that are normally inherently a bit dirty (from a technical cleanliness perspective). The current production lines have been in place for more than a decade and the company is just now dipping it's toes in designing their own PCBs. The know-how at the production stage is therefore poor as of right now, which makes it very, very costly to clean up to say a VDA-19 type line.

Comment: @InsaneMonkey - Then your best approach, IMM, is to contract out the manufacturing of you PWB and assembly of the PCB to a company that has all the equipment and processes in place to give you what your need.  Setting-up your own, in-house PCB manufacturing operation is not a trivial, or low cost matter.